# What is a "kippered computer"?

Tags: meaning

What is a kippered computer? This phrase appears in a novel. My only guess is that "kippered" refers to the appearance of having been stitched together.

Comment: Your guess may be right as to the *intended* meaning. But all four instances of [*a kippered computer*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22a+kippered+computer%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl) on Google Internet refer to your very question here, and there are *no* written instances in Google Books. So it's stretching things a bit to say that's *inherently* what the words mean. Of course, it may mean a completely *ruined* computer, given *done up like a kipper* often means *severely messed up [by violent treatment]*

Comment: (I'm guessing there aren't many contexts where you would *stitch up like a kipper = trick / frame* a computer.)

Comment: The few times I recall seeing "kippered" in the context of a computer it appeared to refer to one that was badly messed up or damaged.

Comment: Could you please add some context. For example: The name of the novel.  The sentence and surrounding paragraph it appears in. And if you know anything else about the computer from reading the novel that isn't conveyed in that paragraph.  My immediate thought is that it means there's something wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

A kipper is a smoked fish, a herring in fact.  So I imagine that a kippered computer is one that has been 'smoked' i.e. burnt out either through electrical fault or overuse.

Answer (score 1):

The google finds a number of slang usages for *kippered*.  The word, usually applied to fish, literally means dried or smoked.  Thus the term "stone kippered" for someone who has spent considerable time high on marijuana.  But I don't think smoke has anything to do with the meaning here.  Rather, I think it means in this context abused, beaten down to injury of disrepair.  I don't think the cites for this are particularly authoritative, so I haven't linked to them, but consider the BBC-4 Radio series *Bleak Expectations*, a send-up of Dickens and named for two of his works *Bleak House* and *Great Expectations*, with their tortured characters and tortuous plots.  Wikipedia sums up the first series of the radio show as follows:

> The plot ... revolves around Philip "Pip" Bin ... and
>   his two sisters, Poppy and Pippa, whose seemingly ideal life is
>   disrupted by the death of their father and the madness of their
>   mother. They are then locked away by their guardian, ... the main
>   villain of the piece ... in St. Bastard's, the most vicious boarding
>   school in England, and St. Bitch's, a nearby convent.

I list the titles of the first season's episodes:

> 1 "A Childhood Cruelly **Kippered**"
>  2   "An Adolescence Utterly
>   Trashed"
>  3   "A Youth Utterly Crocked"
>  4    "A Young Adulthood
>   Bitterly Dismantled"
>  5   "A Young Love Mercilessly
>   Dismembered"
>  6   "A Life Sadly Smashed... Then Happily Restored A
>   Bit"

and from Series 2:

> 1 "A Happy Life, Cruelly Re-**Kippered**"
>  2  "A Re-**Kippered**
>   Life Smashed Some More"

This is a long way around to saying the computer has been worn out by hard use.